# Why does the color-depth of the rendering vary with the order the different images are painted?

Tags: image, histogram, octave

Probably a beginner's question... Why does the color-depth of the rendering vary with the order the histograms are computed / painted?

I use this code in Octave (with Windows 7, 64 bits) with a grayscale .bmp image:

```
pkg load image % Package image    
IMG = imread('A.png'); % Read image    
subplot (1,3,1); % Show original image
imshow(IMG);
title ('Original image');

subplot (1,3,2); % Show 256 bins histogram
imhist(IMG, 256);
title ('Histogram 256 bins');

subplot (1,3,3); % Show 8 bins histogram
imhist(IMG, 8);
title ('Histogram 8 bins');
```

Then the last two blocks are swapped:

```
subplot (1,3,3); % Show 8 bins histogram
imhist(IMG, 8);
title ('Histogram 8 bins');

subplot (1,3,2); % Show 256 bins histogram
imhist(IMG, 256);
title ('Histogram 256 bins');
```

The two results:

[image]

Notice how the number of gray steps in the whole rendering is changed, as if the last histogram computed / painted were driving the whole image color depth.

Here is the original image used (8-bit grayscale):

[image]

Do I miss something I should know about how the final result is affected?